# Deleting comments from the beginning of selected lines

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, visual-mode

I have written a vimscript function to toggle comments on/off on lines selected in visual mode. The function successfully **adds** comments but freezes when I try to uncomment selected lines.

The function is

```
" Function to automatically toggle comments (on visual selection)
function! ToggleComments()
    let cFamilyTypes = ['c', 'cpp', 'cc', 'cxx', 'cs', 'java']
    let commentString = ""
    let commentChar = ''
    let counter = 0 " Indicates if the line was commented, so don't comment again
    if index(cFamilyTypes, &filetype) != -1
        let commentString = "//"
        let commentChar = '/'
    endif
    if &filetype == 'vim'
        let commentString = "\""
        let commentChar = '"'
    endif

    " Check if comments exist at the beginning of the current line and
    " delete them
    call feedkeys("0")
    while getline(".")[col(".")-1] == commentChar || getline(".")[col(".")-1] == ' '  || getline(".")[col(".")-1] == '\t'     
        if getline(".")[col(".")-1] == commentChar
            call feedkeys("x")
            let counter += 1
            continue
        endif
        call feedkeys("l")
    endwhile
    " Code to check and delete existing comments ends here

    " If counter was not incremented, the line is uncommented. So add
    " comments
    if counter == 0
        call feedkeys("0")
        execute "normal! i" . commentString . "\<ESC>"
        let counter = 0
    endif
    " Code to add comments ends here

endfunction
" Function to automatically toggle comments ends here
```

I call the function by `:'<,'>call ToggleComments()`

I am a beginner to vimscript so can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have a look at tpope/commentary’s source code if you’re really interested in toggling comments

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I am aware that plugins exist. However I wanted to implement it myself.

Comment: yes; but no shame in having inspiration from other sources.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using `feedkeys()` here, instead, just use `normal!` to run normal mode commands, e.g. `normal! 0` or `normal! x` etc. Not sure if that will fix all the bugs you have here, just wanted to point this out as a "best practices" kind of thing...

Comment: @filbranden Thank you! It worked. I replaced every `feedkeys()` call by a `execute "normal! <something>"` and it works as intended. Can you post this as an answer, so i can accept it?

Comment: @aks Will do. A bit later though, I'll dig up the reference that `feedkeys()` actually happens *after* your function call. (Anyways, get the exact details straight.) Will post an answer though.

Comment: @aks Posted as an answer! Please leave a comment if you think it can be improved in any way. (Or feel free to edit the answer to propose a change if you like!) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're calling `feedkeys()` and that function adds the keypresses to the end of the typeahead buffer, which means they don't execute right away.

From [`:help feedkeys()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html?#feedkeys%28%29):

> By default the string is added to the end of the typeahead buffer, thus if a mapping is still being executed the characters come after them.

There are flags you can pass to `feedkeys()` to change this behavior... But in any case, the actual *intent* of your commands here is to run Normal mode commands and using [`:normal!`](https://vimhelp.org/various.txt.html?#%3Anormal) is a much better way to accomplish that.

So I suggest you change your code to use `normal! 0`, `normal! x` and `normal! l` instead of the `feedkeys()` calls, that should solve the issue for you.